# Question using this structure "Since ... is ...., could we ...?"

Tags: questions

I want to give a fact and then make a question. like this:

> Since this info is important for investigation, could we store it for later use?

Is that correct?

Comment: Since this sentence is obviously correct, could we ask you why do you think it's not?

Comment: I really don't like the informal *info* used in a formal (or really any written) context.

Comment: 'Could' here is the hedging modal (= 'Do you think that we can' / 'Why don't we') with a hint of the 'Is it allowable?' sense. The verb could be used after many other statements: 'Here's some important evidence. Could ...' / 'As my plate is full at the moment, could ...'. //  'Could we store this information for later use? As it is important to the investigation?' shows that the question is really suggesting a structure where there isn't one.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was not sure if this structure was right. just that @Tushar Raj

Comment: _should_ seems more appropriate. But _could_ has two common senses: one is asking about ability, the other is as a suggestion/request (e.g. _could we get going now?_) The latter fits the sentence in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, correct. "Could we store..?" is the second conditional - a supposed action for present or future.